# Tag for open data discovery/publicizing resources

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I don't have a particular term in mind, but there have been a few questions related to how open data resources are publicized and/or how they are most easily discovered by potential users and I am wondering if there might be a term to describe this that would be a useful tag.

Examples:

- [What are the most common ways that users find out about new data
  sets](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/477/what-are-the-most-common-ways-that-users-find-out-about-new-data-sets)
- [How can I track updates on the release of new open data sources across the world?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/503/how-can-i-track-updates-on-the-release-of-new-open-data-sources-across-the-world)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it seems redundant, but how about data-resource since we may eventually talk about other types of resources such as api-resource, geo-resource, expert-resource, etc.

Comment: +1 I think data-resource sounds good

Answer (score 2):

For the record: Currently we use [releasing-data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/releasing-data) for all "questions related to making data available for others to use". The two example questions are tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Resource ?  Resource location?